# Is there a way to deploy different sets of pods based on context?

Tags: kubernetes

For example, I have three apps that I want to deploy, and a database as well. When running on a dev machine (`docker-for-desktop` context) or in an integration or test cluster, I would want to run 2 replicas of each app, plus have a SQL container that they all connect to. In staging or production, I want to be able to set the replicas as per traffic needs, and I want to connect to a different (external) SQL server.

I would then want those yaml files to be kept in source control, so depending on your env it uses the correct context and "creates" all of the yaml files.

Is this possible with contexts? Or is this a namespace problem? Or do I just need to have yaml files in separate folders (a `local` folder, a `staging` folder, a `production` folder) and have copies of the yaml files in each folder. Or maybe some other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to maintain the same set of YAML files for different configurations, for example:

[Helm](https://helm.sh/)

[Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/)

[ksonnet](https://ksonnet.io/)

You can use these tools to keep only per environment configurations in a different files in git.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Looks like ksonnet is going away, but Kustomize looks exactly like what I needed and Helm looks like that plus a lot more. I'll dig into those two.

Comment: `Helm` has wide community and this is mature tool. Just in case, all tools has one missing point - they cannot build container images. it's not an issue, if you rely on configured private registry and CI. But `Skaffold` could help with wiring local development, image build and k8s resource upgrade in cluster.